# WS2008R2 - Cannot login to local account after disabling Active Directory Domain Services

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, domain, domain-controller

I'm using Hyper-V version 10.0.10586.0 and I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 virtual machine on it, which is a Domain Controller.

I wasn't able to create a new checkpoint on Hyper-V, unless i disable Active Directory Domain Services on VM (i reported this problem [in this SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/1070464/cannot-create-checkpoint-on-hyper-v-0x800423f4) but no success), so I disabled it and created my checkpoint.

After this, i knew that i would be unable to log on to the domain account `sp2013.com\administrator`, but i also have the local account `sp20130\administrator`, but i'm unable to log on to this one too.

Does ADDS disabling also turn local account logon unavailable? I have logged on to local accounts before in this exact scenario, but i don't know what's going on now. Is there any form to gain access again? Some important points:

- I don't have another machine on that domain.
- I was thinking about the [sethc hack](http://www.howtogeek.com/96630/how-to-reset-your-forgotten-windows-password-the-easy-way/) to bypass logon, but i don't know if it's possible on the virtual machine environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no local user accounts on a Domain Controller.

If you merely stopped whatever services you stopped and you didn't disable them then rebooting the VM should fix the issue for you. Use the VM client interface to initiate a restart of the VM.

Comment: Thanks! This worked to me. After rebooting, i was able to log on to `sp20130\administrator` account. Strange. Only a question about the "no local user accounts on a DC". When i reference the local machine name (not the domain) and the user name, it isn't a local account?

Answer (score 1):

If the machine is not the domain controller then perhaps you have the machine name wrong.

Try .\administrator instead of machinename\administrator.  The dot means local machine.

Comment: +1 for the alternate approach to reference the machine name